# Task Manager shows high power usage while gaming

Tags: power, task-manager, amd-ryzen, windows-10-v1809

[image: Power Spike Photo]
[image: Specs Photo]

I turned on my computer today and all of a sudden my power usage was spiking for everything. Not just in games but when i open task manager and watch videos...

I have never seen this happen on my computer before, and it only started today after turning on my computer.

My power supply is a EVGA 600B 80+

My amd integrated graphics is disabled and I am running a EVGA Geforce gtx 1060 superclocked.

Comment: Did you lose your cookie? It looks like you've created two (unregistered) accounts with the same name. Please register for an account, then [contact Stack Exchange](https://superuser.com/contact) for an account merger. For more information, see https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 5):

This is not an issue with the power supply. What you're seeing in Task Manager is a feature introduced with Windows 10 version 1809 intended to help users determine which applications are likely to be using more power, based on the application's CPU and GPU load over time.

On laptops, this information can be used to help determine which applications are draining the battery the most. It's of less concern with desktop PCs, so unless your system is somehow shutting down or otherwise actually experiencing a problem under load, you can ignore this field on a desktop system.

---

You've indicated that you have a GeForce GTX 1060 graphics card installed on your system along with a Ryzen 3 2200G (*Raven Ridge*). As a quick check, make sure your monitor is plugged into the graphics card and not your motherboard; if it's on the motherboard, you're actually using the processor (integrated) graphics and not the graphics card, which means your GPU is in fact sitting idle. Also, you may need to set the system to use the graphics card in the BIOS; be sure it's is configured to use the PCIe slot first for graphics.

Regardless, your configuration does not exceed the capacity of your power supply. The processor requires 65 W, while the graphics card needs 120 W. These, along with the other parts of the system, would at most require only half of the 600 W capacity of your power supply.

Comment: In other words, everything always worked this way, OP just *never saw* it being measured before...

Comment: It is in the correct spot, my integrated graphics has been disabled as i said, i would not see a screen if it was in the wrong slot. it is also set to the correct pcie slot. nothing has changed in the past while, i dont get what any of this has to do with my power usage. Am i having a power bleed somehow somewhere?

Are you taking into consideration my ram, 4 fans, 2 HDD's, m.2, SSD's, cpu fan. I do have fan splitters so my fans can can all run.

Comment: That still won't exceed the capacity of your power supply. You're looking at about 50-80W from the parts you've mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is the logging is paused.

Goto the view tab and set the Update Speed to Normal.

I had a client with the same issue and it was showing the burst load
Of launching task manager and the details captured during this was all that was showed and it wasn’t then capturing real time data which
is of course much lower post loading.