# High power usage?

Tags: graphics-card, power, gaming, task-manager, rendering

I just built a pc with 1050ti. I'll get straight to the point.. When I play games like minecraft with shaders on it or if I render a project in blender I see that the task manager shows that the power usage is very high highlighted by the darkest shade of red which is very intimidating.. Should I be worried about it as in will it increase my electricity bill astronomically? Any explanation would be appreciated.

Also guys if you have an answer please post it as an answer and not a comment so that I can mark it as my answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Task Manager shows high power usage while gaming](https://superuser.com/questions/1381230/task-manager-shows-high-power-usage-while-gaming) The short answer is no, it will not skyrocket your electricity bill.

Comment: @DrZoo Thank you man..I was very concerned about the bill part..Also please post your comment as answer so that I can mark it

Comment: All good man. The duplicate question has the answer, so there's no need to add one here too.